# rsync daemon with enforcing selinux policy rsync_export_all_ro still prevents access to files under /var/spool/postfix/private/

Tags: centos, rsync, selinux

I have a number of Debian-based systems that get backed up regularly using `rsync`. For a number of reasons I have had to deploy a small CentOS 7 server, and I want to add it to my backup schedule. It cannot be backed up using rsync over ssh; instead I need to use the rsync daemon.

CentOS has SELinux enabled in enforcing mode so it's set me off on a steep learning curve.

The `rsyncd` configuration section (simplified)

```
[root]
    comment = Filesystem
    path = /
    exclude = /proc/*** /run/*** /sys/*** [...]
    read only = yes
    list = yes
    uid = root
    secrets file = [...]
    ignore errors = no
    ignore nonreadable = no
    refuse options = delete
```

I believe that the process is labelled correctly:

```
ps -eZ | grep rsync
system_u:system_r:rsync_t:s0    26020 ?        00:00:00 rsync
```

Initially the attempt to backup via the `rsync` daemon failed with all sorts of permission errors which I've attributed to SELinux labels. Digging further I [found a reference](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-rsync_selinux/) to an SELinux policy that permits the `rsync` daemon to export all files read-only:

```
setsebool -P rsync_export_all_ro 1
```

This results in this set

```
getsebool -a | grep '^rsync'
rsync_anon_write --> off
rsync_client --> off
rsync_export_all_ro --> on
rsync_full_access --> off
```

Unfortunately this still doesn't give me access to all files on the system. Specifically I've some files under `/var/spool/postfix/private` that are unreadable:

```
rsync: readlink_stat("/var/spool/postfix/private/defer" (in root)) failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: readlink_stat("/var/spool/postfix/private/trace" (in root)) failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: readlink_stat("/var/spool/postfix/private/verify" (in root)) failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: readlink_stat("/var/spool/postfix/private/proxymap" (in root)) failed: Permission denied (13)
...
```

One sample entry relating to `/var/spool/postfix/private` from `audit2why -a` follows. Note that none of the entries references `rsync_export_all_ro`:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1565118203.332:21775): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=26597 comm="rsync" path="/var/spool/postfix/private/scache" dev="dm-0" ino=9148374 scontext=system_u:system_r:rsync_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:postfix_private_t:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
        Was caused by:
        The boolean rsync_full_access was set incorrectly.
        Description:
        Allow rsync to full access

        Allow access by executing:
        # setsebool -P rsync_full_access 1
```

I don't understand why there's a reference to `rsync_full_access` (which I don't want to set, and shouldn't be triggering anyway) but none to `rsync_export_all_ro`.

In the interests of getting a complete backup, how can I add this directory tree to the set of files that can be exported by the `rsync` daemon? (And for this change to be persistent across reboots.)

Comment: Are you interested in `semanage permissive -a rsync_t` ?

Comment: @Jeff I would have preferred to leave the actual files out of the title so as to keep the question context general

Comment: @Jeff my usual approach is simply to switch off SELinux. This time I'm trying to "do it right". Permissive mode doesn't seem "right" to me. Is it...?

Comment: I like to have something resembling the error or the problem in the title; I took that from the end of the post ("how can I add _this directory tree_"); if the problem is wider, please feel free to adjust it.

Comment: Thanks. More interested (this time) in understanding why the `rsync_export_all_ro` doesn't cover everything like it claims, and how I would go about fixing that.

Comment: Not sure about that one; if it was me, I'd experiment with `rsync_full_access`, just based on the name. I don't know what it does behind the scenes, though.

Comment: Not an answer, since this is news to me, but the [Fedora 22 SELinux User's and Administrator's Guide](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/22/html-single/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/index.html) in 22.3. Booleans says "rsync_export_all_ro -- Having this Boolean enabled allows rsync in the rsync_t domain to export NFS and CIFS volumes with read-only access to clients."

Comment: Does `audit2why`/`audit2allow` tell anything useful? Could you provide (some) relevant AVC entries from audit log?

Comment: @sebasth I hope I've given you a useful sample. There's nothing else relevant in the output. Please let me know if you want something more/else - I'm really not yet familiar with SELinux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right to not wanting to disable SELinux for the `rsync_t` domain. Unfortunately, although the [configurability](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rsync_selinux) of the SELinux implementation for rsync is fairly extensive, there are edge cases where setting the `rsync_export_all_ro` boolean will still *not* allow the rsync daemon to access certain files. There is [one Bugzilla entry](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1263770) which closely resembles your troubles. The suggestion given there is to use `rsync_full_access` to overcome the problem, albeit impairing security (it is still better than `semanage permissive -a rsync_t` though).

### Creating custom policy module

So, to answer your question, if you want to use the safer option `rsync_export_all_ro` *and* be able to let the rsync daemon access the "edge case" files/directories, you need to create your own policy module.

This is done by letting the rsync daemon do it's work in permissive mode, capturing AVC denials as it goes along, and then converting the AVC denials to a policy, like so:

```bsh
# put SELinux in permissive mode
setenforce 0

# --- do your rsync stuff ---

# get related AVC denials
# I'm using 'recent' here, depending on the rsync run time please adjust accordingly
ausearch -m avc -ts recent --subject rsync_t

# go through the output. If you're satisfied, create the module
ausearch -m avc -ts recent --subject rsync_t | audit2allow -m roaima-rsync-custom-1 > roaima-rsync-custom-1.te
checkmodule -M -m -o roaima-rsync-custom-1.mod roaima-rsync-custom-1.te
semodule_package -o roaima-rsync-custom-1.pp -m roaima-rsync-custom-1.mod

# load the policy module
semodule -i roaima-rsync-custom-1.pp

# disable permissive mode
setenforce 1

# --- do your rsync stuff again --
```

### Catching AVC denials that aren't audited ("dontaudit")

If for some reason, the "edge case" files still aren't accessible and the `ausearch` command doesn't yield results, you may be hitting a "dontaudit" rule.

To rebuild the SELinux policy ignoring all "dontaudit"-rules, run `semodule -DB`. The `-D` option disables "dontaudit" rules; the `-B` option rebuilds the policy.

Then try if you can trigger audit log events. If so, capture them like I showed above, create the SELinux module, and then re-enable "dontaudit" rules by running: `semodule -B`.

For a full list of "dontaudit" rules, run the `sesearch --dontaudit` command. Narrow down searches using the `-s` domain option and the `grep` command. For example: `sesearch --dontaudit -s rsync_t`.